# Print Values from a Sequence of Entries / ComboBoxes

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to build a program to add a basketball lineup.

Ideally I want the output to be (as an example):
Center, John
Point Guard, Jack
Shooting Guard, James

This would depend on how many values you add and what you type for the name. I am struggling to pull these values that are entered. I am not getting an error - just not getting the results I am looking for. For example, instead of "Point Guard", it says "". I am also not returning a value for the Entry fields. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

'''

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk() 
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

combovalues = ['Center' , 'Point Guard' , 'Shooting Guard' , 'Power Forward' , 'Small Forward' ]
startinglineup = []
entry_values = []


root.counter = 2
my_lineup = []
string_var = tk.StringVar()
entry_values.append(string_var)

def addlineup():

    Label(root, text='Lineup Name').grid(row=0) 
    e1 = Entry(root) 
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, values=combovalues)
    combobox.grid(column=0, row=1)
    e2 = Entry(root)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    addbutton = tk.Button(root, text='Add', width=25, command=add) 
    addbutton.grid(column=0, row=14)
    confirmbutton = tk.Button(root, text='Confirm', width=25, command=save)
    confirmbutton.grid(column=0, row=15)


def save():
    number = root.counter
    print(my_lineup)


def add():
    root.counter += 1
    combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, values=combovalues)
    combobox.grid(column=0, row=root.counter)
    entry = Entry(root) 
    entry.grid(row=root.counter, column=1)
    for stringvar in entry_values:
        text = string_var.get()
        if text:
            my_lineup.append(text)
    my_lineup.append([text, combobox])



# --- main menu ---
filemenu = Menu(menu) 
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu) 


# --- lineups ----
lineupmenu = Menu(menu) 
menu.add_cascade(label='Lineups', menu=lineupmenu) 
lineupmenu.add_command(label='Add Lineup', command=addlineup)
lineupmenu.add_command(label='View Lineups')


mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: What are the purposes of these variables: `startinglineup`, `entry_values`, `my_lineup` and `string_var`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get results from an entry:

1. **Create a `StringVar()`** (If you want to store the result in a different variable and not the `Entry` itself)

```py
string_var = tk.StringVar()
```

2. **Creat an `Entry`**

```py
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=string_var)
entry.pack()
```

*Remember to add `string_var` to the parameter `textvariable`, `textvariable=string_var`.*

3. **Finally, get the result** (it can be done at any time)

```py
result = string_var.get()
```

**Or, you can just do** (If you don't care to store the result in the `Entry` itself) **:**

```py
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack() 

result = entry.get()
```

*You don't actually need a `StringVar`*

Comment: Just to be clear, this is one way to get the value, but not the only way. You don't need to use `textvariable` - you can call `get()` directly on the entry widget.

Comment: @MC2020 's problem is: a `StringVar` was created, and then an `Entry`, then `.get()` was called on the `StringVar`. But the `StringVar` was never put into the `Entry`, so the `StringVar` is empty.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the comment/advice. Unfortunately I am still returning a blank value when I enter print(result). Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: @MC2020 The problem I see in your code is you are calling `.get()` on an empty `StringVar`. You can set the entry's `textvariable` to a `StringVar` (try this and you'll see what I mean: `e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=entry_values[-1])` and then if you want, print the `StringVar`: `print(entry_values[-1].get())`). I tried this on your code and it worked. Or you can just call `.get()` on the entry itself (you would have to change the code so the entries are in a `list`).